# How to calculate and display the average of the 5 numbers in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate and display the average of the 5 numbers in c++, I am  challenging my self not to use: global variables, labels or go-to statements, infinite loops, and break statements to exit loops. And I am being stuck can any one help me solve this problem: where I need to prompt the user to end 5 numbers and then calculate and display the average of the 5 numbers. Thanks.

here is the code of what I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // create a variable x.
    int x; 
    // create a variable called average to get the 5 numbers
    // calculation. 
    int average; 

    // Prompt the user to enter five numbers. 
    cout << "Please enter five numbers." << endl;
    cout << average << endl;

  // Calculate the five numbers. 
    average = x;
    cout << "The average for the five numbers are:" << average << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Use `cin` to read in the 5 numbers.

Comment: Your comments in the code are a bit confusing, can you please mention it somewhere, whether you want to take the input from same variable and assign the average to it or take the input in one variable and then assign the average to the other variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have solved my own question. As I said I am avoiding `global variables, labels or go-to statements, infinite loops, and break statements to exit loops`. So, here is my answer:

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 // Creating variables.
 float v, w, x, y, z, average;
 // Prompting the user to enter first number.
 cout << "Please enter first number: ";

 // Getting the input from the user.
 cin >> v;
 // Prompting the user to enter second number.
 cout << "Please enter second number ";

 // Getting the input from the users.
 cin >> w;
 // Prompting the user to enter third number.
 cout << "Please enter third number ";

 // Getting the input from the user.
 cin >> x;
 // Prompting the user to enter fourth number.
 cout << "Please enter fourth number ";

 // Getting the input from the user.
 cin >> y;

 // Prompting the user to enter fifth number.
 cout << "Please enter fifth number ";

 // Getting the input from the user.
 cin >> z;
 // Calculating the average of those user input five numbers.
 average = (v + w + x + y + z) / 5; 

// Displaying the total average of the five numbers entered.
 cout << "The average of the five numbers is:" << average << endl;
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is very basic. I think the guy who asked this question already knew about it. If you code it this way, its not a big of a challenge. I think the aim of the question was to check a different approach if possible without simply using 5 variables to store 5 inputs. This is old school.

Comment: Still.. nice try.. but what happens if there are a hundred inputs?

Comment: yeah I know for loops and while loops come in along smarter, but I try to prevent those by doing it that way, to brush up my C++ Skills.

Comment: Yeah.. did you read the one that I have posted after the editing, that is called **Recursion**, _there is no global variables, labels or go-to statements, infinite loops, and break statements to exit loops_. I might have taken 5 as fixed, but if that is taken from user input, then whole code will work upto the number of times the user wants.

Comment: didn't see that coming, so best of luck brushing your skills after all.

Answer (score 3):

Solution using arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    vector<double> nums;
    double sum = 0.0, average;

    cout<<"Enter the numbers of elements: ";
    cin>>n;


    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout<<"Enter number: "<<i+1;
        cin>>num[i];
        sum += num[i];
    }

    average = sum / n;
    cout<<"Average = "<<average

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use `std::vector<double> nums;`

Comment: Definitely a better approach, thumbs up for that :)

Comment: or at least check the the user didn't enter 999999 for the number of elements (anything > 100).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code, the variables that I have used are very much similar to the one you have used (this is just a code snippet):

```
int x;
int sum=0; 
cout << "Please enter five numbers." << endl;
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    cin>>x;
    sum += x;
}
cout << sum/5.0 << endl;
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to use a loop at all then here is what you can do using a technique called recursion:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int calc(int sum, int i){ 
    if(i == 0){
        return sum;
    }else{
        int x;
        std::cin>>x;
        i--;
        sum+=x + calc(sum, i);
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
  int i=5;
  int sum=0;
  sum = calc(sum, i);
  std::cout<<std::endl<<sum/5.0;
  return 0;
}
```

### Here is a [link](http://cpp.sh/8erm) to the editor that i used.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: The `average` variable is misnamed. At no time does it contain an average. It should be called `sum`, `total`, etc.

Comment: Yes it is misnamed, I just used the same naming convention as given in the question, because otherwise it can be difficult to understand for him.

Comment: Yeah but I am challenging my self not to use for(;;) ....and possible not infinite loops.

Comment: try without the for(;;)

Comment: Then there is only one way in my mind, you have to use recursion. There you dont need a loop. Let me try and provide you with an example.

Comment: Check my own answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here's some code that should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    float x = 0; 
    int i;
    int a;
    int size;

    cout << "How many numbers? ";
    cin>> size;
    for (i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        cout << "Please enter number #" << i << ": ";
        cin >>a;
        x += a;
    }

    cout << "The average for the five numbers are: " << x/(float)size << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can just enter 5 when the program asks for how many numbers (It just lets you find the average of an number of values). Hope this helps!

Comment: The cast of size to float is not needed.